# How python compares nested sequences

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested, comparison, tuples

So I got into something I don't understand. Given:

```
table  # Type: tuple(tuple(str)).
data  # Type: list(list(str)). Both ordered by rows.
```

When running following two comparisons output is different and I want to know the reason of first output:

```
table == tuple(tuple(x for x in row) for row in data) -> False
all(table[i] == tuple(data[i]) for i in xrange(len(table))) -> True
```

How does `==` work for nested and not nested sequences?

Data on which comparison is made:

```
data  = [['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'], ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3'], ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['11', '2', '3', '1'], ['1.1', '2.2', '3.3', '4.0'], ['11', '2', '3', '1'], ['Area', '', 'None', 'Area Error']]
table = (('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'), ('A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3'), ('A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'), ('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('11', '2', '3', '1'), ('1.1', '2.2', '3.3', '4.0'), ('11', '2', '3', '1'), ('Area', '', 'None', 'Area Error'))
```

## SOLUTION

Sorry I spotted it after I checked it in interactive prompt. `table` is an attribute of some other object called `rows`. The error I made is that I was too much used to passing `rows` where indexing and iterators appeared (which were returning `rows.table` elements) that I forgot it's different structure than `table`. Actual error:

```
rows == tuple(tuple(x for x in row) for row in data)  # Should be `rows.table`.
```

Sorry for mess. **However comparison question still holds.**

Comment: can you give sample data for table and data

Comment: Show us code we can actually run, that actually demonstrates the problem when run. The `all` version you posted should have given a `TypeError`, specifically `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.

Comment: I suspect that `data` is actually longer than `table`. `table` might even be empty.

Comment: Now that you've fixed the typo, I get `True` for both tests on Python 2.6 with that `data` and `table`. BTW, `tuple(row)` returns the same thing as `tuple(x for x in row)` except that it's shorter & more efficient.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question** : *How does == work for nested and not nested sequences?*

The comparison i.e. `==` works only on literals i.e. int, string etc. However when we compare nested data types like `lists,list of lists` or something with high level of nesting for example `list of dictionaries with key as string and values as tuples of integers`, the comparison will work in depth first manner on `(literal, position on literal)` pairs present in nesting. Below is an example code to support my argument:

*Note that each class is allowed to overload the `==` method as per their own requirements.*

```
# The following method compares both nested as well as non-nested data
# and returns True or False.
# for simplicity let us restrict ourself to  basic data-types like
# list,dict,set,tuple,int,float,bool and string.

 basicTypes = [type(1),type(1.0),type("shasha"),type(True)]

def comp(o1,o2):
   if type(o1) == type(o2) and type(o1) not in basicTypes and len(o1) == len(o2):
        if type(o1) == type({}):
            o1 = o1.items()
            o2 = o2.items()

        for a,b in zip(o1,o2):
            if not comp(a,b):
                return False
        return True

    elif type(o1) == type(o2) and type(o1) in basicTypes:
        return o1 == o2

    return False
```

**Test cases:**

```
a= ['a', 1, [2, 3, {1:2, 2:3, 3:[1, 2, 3], 4:{1:2, 2:True }}], {1:[1,2,"sja"],2:{1:2, 2:3}}, (1,2),[(1, 2),{1:2}]]
b= ['a', 1, [2, 3, {1:2, 2:3, 3:[1, 2, 3], 4:{1:2, 2:True }}], {1:[1,2,"sja"],2:{1:2, 2:3}}, (1,2),[(1, 2),{1:2}]]

print(comp(a,b))  #True

a= ['a', 1, [2, 3, {1:2, 2:3, 3:[1, 2, 3], 4:{1:2, 2:True }}], {1:[1,2,"sja"], 5:4}, (1,2),[(1, 2),{1:2}]]
b= ['a', 1, [2, 3, {1:2, 2:3, 3:[1, 2, 3], 4:{1:2, 2:True }}], {1:[1,2,"sja"], 5:2}, (1,2),[(1, 2),{1:2}]]

print(comp(a,b)) #False

a=5
b="shasha"

print(comp(a,b)) #False

a=4
b=5

print(comp(a,b)) #False
```

Comment: `comp()` implementation explains it really well. I've recently read about in in "Learning Python" by Mark Lutz and it's said that sequences/mapping comparison compare their items one by one (if not hashable).
However i don't know if it happens in BFS or DFS manner.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `)` in the `all` line. When I add the missing paren, I get that both lines return true:

```
data  = [['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'], ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3'], ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['11', '2', '3', '1'], ['1.1', '2.2', '3.3', '4.0'], ['11', '2', '3', '1'], ['Area', '', 'None', 'Area Error']]
table = (('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'), ('A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3'), ('A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'), ('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('11', '2', '3', '1'), ('1.1', '2.2', '3.3', '4.0'), ('11', '2', '3', '1'), ('Area', '', 'None', 'Area Error'))

print table == tuple(tuple(x for x in row) for row in data)  # True
print all(table[i] == tuple(data[i]) for i in xrange(len(table)))  # True
```